# Validate Knime File Reader

Tags: validation, etl, knime

I need to capture rejected records while reading files for 2 cases.
If number of columns is less or more than configured header & if there is any data type mismatch (Integer value coming as String). I used FileReader Node, for both the cases instead of rejecting those records FileReader node is failing.

Comment: What are rejected records? File Reader can't simply reads data into KNIME and can not have any rules like you mentioned defined.

Comment: Rejected record in the sense, if a record in file is less than or more than X columns, then I want to reject only that record not the entire file. Is any node to validate each record in a file.. Table Validator does but for the entire file I want record level validator.

Comment: If I got you right there is no such node and you would need to build such logic after complete data is red into KNIME

Comment: Thank you, I am currently doing the same. Talend had tFileInputDelimited i was looking for its equivalent in knime.